# Search field per column for an html table

Tags: html, search, html-table

I'm working on an html table. I need it to have a search field (no plugins, for security reasons I can't use one) for each column and to filter results (that is, remove rows that don't contain what is being typed in). If more than one field has something typed in, I need the table to be filtered by all fields. So for instance, if I have five columns (A,B,C,D and E), if I type in "1" on the field for column A and "2" on column C, I would like for the table to only display rows that contain 1 on A and 2 on C, but not rows that contain only one of those results.

So far I was able to do the following (and with help, I know some html but zero Javascript or jQuery): I created a table, with one single search field, that searches on the first column. I need an additional search field for the next column and additional columns (the table has a total of 11 columns but I didn't want to paste too much code, so I did it of only two columns for this post.

The code is:

Script

```
function myFunction() {
 // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search 
query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
if (td) {
  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
  } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

CSS:

```
#myInput {
background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
/* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
/* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Search Field and Table:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

[image: Here's an image of what I would like to achieve.]

It's my first time posting, so I hope I made the post nice and clear.

Comment: Why isn't it working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi! The code itself is working, but it's for one search field only. I need to expand that to more than one search field. I need one per column